# Scheduled posting to Facebook in PHP cURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have been trying to post a status at scheduled date/time to Facebook using PHP cURL.

I am using the unix timestamp value to the parameter `scheduled_publish_time` and `published=false`. In Facebook I can see my post being scheduled at the given time.

but unfortunately nothing gets posted at that time and Facebook still shows the message as "next post scheduled for #time" even after the time has elapsed.

## Code:

```
<?php
  $facebook_page_id='xxx';    
  $facebook_page_access_token="xxx";
     
  //Facebook page post
  $status='scheduled post'; 
  $fb_page_post="https://graph.facebook.com/{$facebook_page_id}/feeds?message=$status&scheduled_publish_time=1431683900&published=false&access_token=$facebook_page_access_token";
 
  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fb_page_post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 
  $fb_page_post = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
 
  var_dump($fb_page_post);
```

when I run this script through terminal and `var_dump()` the response it gives me an output as :

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
["id"]=>
string(16) "1414369492218829"
["post_id"]=>
string(33) "1387602394895539_1414369492218829"
}
```

what is the solution for this ? What necessary changes do I need to make ?

Thank you for any Help

Comment: Post your code so people can respond to it and see what the issue is.

Comment: Okay. Here I posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `published=false`. It means that no feed story should be created, *at all*.

Using `scheduled_publish_time` *only* is what you need to create a scheduled post, that will only appear on the page’s timeline when the specified timestamp is reached.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#scheduledposts

Comment: if I remove published=false it gives me an error "error(100) : You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post "

Comment: OK, then the docs are ambiguous on that. I suggest you file a bug report with Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs